# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы owl-carousel не менял высоту слайдов во время прокручивания при display: none у родителя?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Есть такой код:
https://jsfiddle.net/gfy6w508/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click-to-me">click to me</a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let $slider =  $('.owl-carousel');
let slide = 0;

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        smartSpeed: 600,
        items: 3,
        autoHeight: true,
        dots: false,
        margin: 20,
        mouseDrag: false,
})

let $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$('.click-to-me').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  slide++;
  $wrapper.css('display', 'none');
  $slider.trigger('to.owl.carousel', slide);
  $wrapper.css('display', 'block');

  // Если убрать эту строку, то слайды после нажатия на кнопку вообще пропадут.
  $slider.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

При нажатии на ссылку `click to me` owl-carousel зачем-то сжимает слайды до нулевой высоты, а потом восстанавливает их высоту. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило? С двумя условиями:

1. Нельзя убирать display: none у родителя (либо можно, но надо как-то скрыть слайдер. И при этом, чтобы пространство, занимаемое им, не оставалось (`visiblity: hidden` не подойдет)).
2. Нельзя убирать `autoHeight: true` в настройках слайдера.

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы в итоге хотите добиться? Что должно произойти при нажатии на кнопку?